# wp_dropdown_categories() scripts working erratically on sidebar

Tags: categories, javascript, archives, dropdown

(Posted this on the WordPress forum, but the notification of a reply went to my spam folder, so now it's dropped off the radar.)

I have three dropdown menus in the site’s sidebar to create views by category for a product line: by model type, by year produced, or by status. Each of these simply pulls posts in a particular category, and redirects to an archive page to display the list.

Each has unique names for variables and functions, and each works…but *only* if it is placed first in the sidebar. The other two, whichever ones they are, will not work. Shifting their position always causes the one that comes first to work, and the other two to be nonfunctional.

I've also tried copying the entire function (`wp_dropdown_categories()`, from `wp-includes/category-template.php`), pasting it into my `functions.php` file three times, and customizing each one so the menus aren't calling the same function. Still doesn't work.

Anyway, this is the entire code for that section:

```
    <div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Model Type</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select model type&include=18,19,20,21'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownModel = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChangeModel() {
           if ( dropdownModel.options[dropdownModel.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownModel.options[dropdownModel.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownModel.onchange = onCatChangeModel;
     --></script>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Year Produced</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select year produced&include=7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownYear = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChangeYear() {
           if ( dropdownYear.options[dropdownYear.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownYear.options[dropdownYear.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownYear.onchange = onCatChangeYear;
     --></script>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Identified/Unidentified</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select status&include=22,23'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownStatus = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChangeStatus() {
           if ( dropdownStatus.options[dropdownStatus.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownStatus.options[dropdownStatus.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownStatus.onchange = onCatChangeStatus;
     --></script>
  </div>
```

Again, each of these works, just not all on the same page. Does anyone have any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the original code is not working is because each category dropdown `<select>` element has an HTML id of `cat`. The JavaScript snipets are looking for the element with the ID of `cat`, but there are 3 of them. IDs should always be unique in the markup.

[`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) does allow the id to be customized, so we can add a unique id to each category dropdown and make the appropriate adjustments to the JS:

```
<div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Model Type</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select model type&include=18,19,20,21&id=model_type'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownModel = document.getElementById("model_type");
        function onCatChangeModel() {
           if ( dropdownModel.options[dropdownModel.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownModel.options[dropdownModel.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownModel.onchange = onCatChangeModel;
     --></script>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Year Produced</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select year produced&include=7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17&id=year_produced'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownYear = document.getElementById("year_produced");
        function onCatChangeYear() {
           if ( dropdownYear.options[dropdownYear.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownYear.options[dropdownYear.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownYear.onchange = onCatChangeYear;
     --></script>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarItem">
     <h4>Identified/Unidentified</h4>
     <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select status&include=22,23&id=identified_status'); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var dropdownStatus = document.getElementById("identified_status");
        function onCatChangeStatus() {
           if ( dropdownStatus.options[dropdownStatus.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
              location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
     ?>/?cat="+dropdownStatus.options[dropdownStatus.selectedIndex].value;
           }
        }
        dropdownStatus.onchange = onCatChangeStatus;
     --></script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Dave, the instructions say not to use comments for thanks, but I don't understand how this system works and can't find any other way to thank you and let you know that your solution worked. I thought I had caught everything that needed to be customized for each script, but I missed that. I guess misusing the comments is -1 for me, but what the hell...courtesy takes precedence.

Comment: Glad that worked, 1db, and thank you! :-) To accept the answer, please click the checkmark next to the answer. This will close it out of the unanswered queue.